# Why am I getting the previous tabs url?

Tags: node.js, selenium, webdriver-io

I am trying to get the url of the window that is opened by clicking the element with id 'wrpr_1431108056877h'. The new window opens but getTitle() still returns the title of the original tab. On the video provided by Browserstack I am able to verify that the current tab is indeed the one that I am trying to access.

```
browser
    .click('#wrpr_1431108056877h')
    .pause(5000)
    .getTitle()
    .then((url: any) => {
        console.log(url);
    })
    .end()
    .catch((err: any) => {
      console.log(err.message);
      done(Error('Could not move'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`browser.getTabIds();`

should give you a list of all the window handles that webdriver knows about.

then you can use

`browser.getCurrentTabId();`

to figure out which window is currently in focus (Maybe this is what you said you are doing from the BrowserStack video?)

My guess is that the newly opened window isn't the currently focused window. Hence any commands executed (like `getTitle()`) will happen on the previous window.

You can switch the focused window to the newly opened window by calling

`browser.switchTab(windowHandle)`

Then you can call `getTitle()` and it should return the correct title.

See the web driver docs on Window here: http://webdriver.io/api/window/getTabIds.html

(scroll all the down on the left hand side to see the complete Window section)

for more info.

Comment: I appreciate your response but I've already tried that, it has not made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Please call

```
 browser.navigate().refresh()
```

Before calling

```
 browser.gettitle().
```

Comment: Mahmud, did you read the question?! **:)** You're probably talking about WebdriverJS, not WebdriverIO... relatives, but different beasts.

Comment: @iamdanchiv i wrote relative code. you can apply this logic on webdriverio. the logic is calling navigate refreseh type method before get title method

Comment: Yes, but still, it can be confusing for the person asking, especially if he doesn't know the server endpoints that are being accessed for the respective information. Also, he's use-case was getting the title of a newly-opened window and WDIO treats this in a different way.

Comment: @iamdanchiv yeah i know but for wdio after navigating to new page and immediately calling get title method you will get the previous url title for sure. so to avoid this after navigating to new page then calling driver url refresh method solve the issue. please try with this.

Comment: @MahmudRiad I've modified my promise chain to look like this 
`client
        .click('#wrpr_1431108056877h')
        .refresh()
        .pause(3000)
        .getUrl()
        .then((url: any) => {
            console.log(url);
        })` 

but I am still getting the same result. Is that the correct implementation of your and @iamdanchiv 's  suggestion?

Comment: Yeas but can you please put refresh after pause method.